# Cover body with background-image

Tags: html, css, background

I have a webpage with a fixed `height`. Now I want to fill the whole `body` with a background-image. The background has to **zoom-to-fit**.

I tried the `background-size: cover`, which does exactly what I want, though the `height` overflows the `body`. An example: http://jsfiddle.net/7c6o4aox/1/.

How do I make the background-image cover only the body? Is it possible to set a `max-height` on the background?

Comment: You can set `background-position: bottom;` on `body`

Comment: @NenadVracar True, but then it will zoom to the bottom when the screen gets too wide, instead of zooming to the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the tendency of the browsers to let properties of `body` be used by `html` as well. In this case, the background-image is applied to `html`.

To avoid this, one solution is to put a wrapper element around the whole page content, and give most of the styles you used for body to it. Properties for, in this case, `main` don't get applied higher up in the DOM tree.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  background: url(http://met.live.mediaspanonline.com/assets/31069/example-608web_w608.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
#content {
  border: solid red 3px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="content">
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</main>
```